Useffect hook doesn't prevent multiple bluetooth device connection react native ble
I'm creating an app in which a phone will connect to one bluetooth peripheral device and receive a data stream of locations from it. If there are multiple available bluetooth peripherals, my current code keeps connecting to all of them regardless of the flags I've put in the connection process. New to React Native, any help would be appreciated.
(the permissions part has been left out as I've verified those are granted).
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [connectedDeviceId, setConnectedDeviceId] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const [position, setPosition] = useState<Position>({
    latitude: 37.78825,
    longitude: -122.4324,
  });

  const connectToDevice = useCallback(async (peripheralId: string) => {
    if (!isConnected) {
    try {
      await BleManager.connect(peripheralId);
      console.log('Connected to', peripheralId);
      setIsConnected(true);
      setConnectedDeviceId(peripheralId);

      await BleManager.retrieveServices(peripheralId);
      console.log('Retrieved services');

      await BleManager.startNotification(peripheralId, SERVICE_UUID, CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);
      console.log('Notification started');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Connection process failed:', error);
      setIsConnected(false);
      setConnectedDeviceId(null);
    }
  }
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    BleManager.enableBluetooth()
      .then(() => {
        // Success code
        console.log("The bluetooth is already enabled or the user confirm");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Failure code
        console.log("The user refuse to enable bluetooth");
      });

    // Initialize BLE Manager
    BleManager.start({ showAlert: false }).then(() => {
      // Success code
      console.log("Module initialized");
    });

    // Scan and connect to the device
    if (!isConnected) {
    BleManager.scan([], 120, true).then(() => {
      console.log('Scanning...');
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Scan failed:', error);
    });
    }

    const handleDisconnectedPeripheral = (data: { peripheral: string }) => {
      console.log('Disconnected from ' + data.peripheral);
      setIsConnected(false);
      setConnectedDeviceId(null);
    };

    const handleDiscoverPeripheral = (peripheral: { id: string; name: string }) => {
      if (peripheral.name === 'GPS_Location_Sender' && !isConnected && !connectedDeviceId) {
        BleManager.stopScan();
        connectToDevice(peripheral.id);
      }
    };

    const handleUpdate = (data: { value: number[], peripheral: string, characteristic: string }) => {
       (works as intended)
    };

    bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral', handleDiscoverPeripheral);
    bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDisconnectPeripheral', handleDisconnectedPeripheral);
    bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic', handleUpdate);

    return () => {
      bleManagerEmitter.removeAllListeners('BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral');
      bleManagerEmitter.removeAllListeners('BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic');
    };
  }, [isConnected, connectedDeviceId, isScanning]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        region={region}
      >
        <Marker coordinate={position} />
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};

I've tried using the UseState hook and some boolean flags to try and prevent the app from connecting to multiple bluetooth peripherals at once, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Your issue is your dependency arrays for both the useCallback and useEffect. Your useEffect uses connectToDevice so that should be in its dependency array; and connectToDevice uses isConnected so that should be in its dependency array
